# Inconsistent spacing between icons

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

```
function parseESG(cellvalue, options, rowObject){ 
    var esgIcons = "";
    var esgValues = rowObject.EsgPillar;
    var esgArr;
    if(typeof esgValues === 'string'){
     esgArr = esgValues.split(",");
    }
    if(esgArr != undefined || esgArr != null){
        
        esgArr.forEach(function(element){
            if(element.trim() === "E"){
                esgIcons += '<img src ="../repo/app/img/pillars-environment.svg" title="'+environmental+'" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-right: 1px; width:20%"> ';
            }
            if(element.trim() === "S"){
                esgIcons += '<img src ="../repo/app/img/pillars-social.svg" title="'+social+'" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-right: 1px; width:20%">';
            }
            if(element.trim() === "G"){
                esgIcons += '<img src = "../repo/app/img/pillars-governance.svg" title="'+governance+'" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-right: 1px; width:20%">'   ;
            }
            }
        );
        
    }
    return "<div style='text-align: center !important;'>"+esgIcons+"</div";
}
```

[Inconsistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFrb.png)

The above code is the code for the icons that is been pasted by me. My problem is that as you can see there is a little gap between the icons. Is there a way to remove that gap? and no border is been added

Answer (score 0):

You can simply given them `margin: auto` or `margin: none` as per your suitability.
Secondly, I see a small error in your code or maybe that's just a copying mistake in the `return` statement. Change `return "<div style='text-align: center !important;'>"+esgIcons+"</div";` to `return "<div style='text-align: center !important;'>"+esgIcons+"</div>";` *(simply closing the div tag)*.

Comment: i mentioned margin as auto and none either didnt work

Comment: Try changing on the comment I mentioned. If you could also share your whole HTML and CSS code, that would be helpful (send html from dev tools - inspect)

Comment: <td role="gridcell" style="" aria-describedby="listDetail_EsgPillar"><div style="text-align: center !important;"><img src="../repo/app/img/pillars-environment.svg" title="Environmental" style="/* margin-left: 1px; *//* margin-right: 1px; */width:20%;margin: auto;"> <img src="../repo/app/img/pillars-social.svg" title="Social" style="/* margin-left: 1px; *//* margin-right: 1px; */width:20%;margin: auto;"><img src="../repo/app/img/pillars-governance.svg" title="Governance" style="/* margin-left: 1px; *//* margin-right: 1px; */width:20%;margin: auto;"></div></td>

Comment: Look at your `margin-right` and `margin-left`.

Comment: i commented it out

Comment: even though i commented it out it is in the same way

Comment: I have no idea why, but I simply gave the second `img` a margin left of `-4.5px and it works`. Try this out:

Comment: yes that works but is there any proper reason why it is happing like that

Comment: Mostly because there's a default margin that we're unable to override.